# How can I default labels to English when not found in other language in MapBox?

Tags: mapbox, multilingual

I'm attempting to support Spanish users of my map, and have figured out how to set all the label layers to a certain language:

```
const langCode = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "en" | "es";
const layers = this.mapbox.getStyle().layers.filter((it) => it.id.includes("label"))
layers.forEach((layer) => {
  this.mapbox.setLayoutProperty(layer.id, "text-field", [
    "get",
    `name_${langCode}`
  ])
});
```

The issue is that half the map ends up empty in Spanish mode.  What I would like is for English to be the default back-up if nothing else exists.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use coalesce to set up default value to english

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#coalesce
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fallback-image/

I guess the code would look like this

```
layers.forEach((layer) => {
  this.mapbox.setLayoutProperty(layer.id, "text-field", [
    "coalesce",
    ["get", `name_${langCode}`],
    // default to english if not found
    ["get", `name_en`],
  ])
})
```

Comment: For me this worked only when making this minor change to the fallback language: ["get", `name`] instead of ["get", `name_en`],